# Rails transparent child relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic relationship, and I would like the child (polymorph?) to be completely transparent.  The setup is generic:

```
class ScheduledEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :scheduleable, polymorphic:true
    #has column names like #starts_at, #ends_at
end
class AppointmentTypeOne < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :scheduled_event, :as=>:scheduleable, :dependent=>:destroy
end
class AppointmentTypeTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :scheduled_event, :as=>:scheduleable, :dependent=>:destroy
end
```

I would like to be able to treat `AppointmentTypeOne` and `AppointmentTypeTwo` as if THEY had the `#starts_at` and `#ends_at` table columns.

Method-wise it's very easy to add `#starts_at`, `#starts_at=`, etc to my `AppointmentX` classes, and refere back to `ScheduledEvent`.  But how can I setup so that the relationship is transparent to `ActiveRelation` also? Letting me do something like:

```
AppointmentTypeOne.where('starts_at IS NOT NULL')
```

(not having to `join` or `include` `:scheduled_event`)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use Single Table Inheritance, not a has_one association.  That will allow you to create subclasses of `ScheduledEvent` for each appointment type:

```
class ScheduledEvent < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class AppointmentTypeOne < ScheduledEvent

end

class AppointmentTypeTwo < ScheduledEvent

end
```

Basically, you add a type column to your scheduled_events table, and rails takes care of the rest.

This forum post covers all of the details: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3815